# I am confused** with "if $\mu(A)<\infty$, then $F$ may be chosen to be compact."

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Assume a subset $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is Lebesgue measurable, then for every $\epsilon>0$ there is an open set $G$ and a closed set $F$ such that $F\subset A\subset G$, and if $\mu(A)<\infty$, then $F$ may be chosen to be compact.

**Question, I am confused** with "if $\mu(A)<\infty$, then $F$ may be chosen to be compact."

**On one hand,** in order to have $F$ be compact, it needs to be at least bounded, **on the other hand** I know that "if $A$ is Lebesgue measurable, then $\mu (A)=sup\{\mu(K): K\subset A, K compact\}$." Which seems like that I do not need $A$ to be finite measure to have the result... **What am I missing?**

Comment: I think there is a condition missing there, involving $\epsilon.$ Otherwise, $F=\emptyset$ is an easy example that works for all $A,$ even when non-measurable!

Comment: You've left out the crucial bit: that $\mu(G)-\mu(F)<\epsilon$ (or that $\mu(A)-\mu(F)$ and $\mu(G)-\mu(A)$ are each $<\epsilon$; regardless of how it's phrased, the important point is that $F$ and $G$ are each "close" to $A$).

Comment: @NoahSchweber Are you saying that if $\mu (A)$ is not bounded then we could have the case $\infty-\infty$? But knowing that if $A$ is Lebesgue measurable, then $\mu(A)=sup\{\mu(K):K\subset A, K compact\}$ we then have $\mu(A\F)<\epsilon$?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Without $\mu (A)<\infty$, can't we still have $\mu(G\setminus K)=\mu(G\setminus A)+\mu(A\setminus K)<\epsilon$?

Comment: @2ndaccount No - if $K$ is compact, then $\mu(K)$ is finite. if $\mu(A)=\infty$, then $\mu(A\setminus K)=\infty$.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that since $A$ is the union of its compact subsets, that there must be a compact subset of $A$ "close to" $A$ itself; this isn't true. For a similar situation think about how, even though $\mathbb{N}$ is the union of finite sets, $\mathbb{N}$ isn't finite.